# How to generate random float numbers?

Tags: python, random

I want to generate random number between 0 and 1 in **python code**  but only get 2 numbers after sign .
Example:

```
 0.22 
 0.25
 0.9
```

I have searched many sources but have not found the solution. Can you help me?

Comment: What kind of radom generator function are you using? I am curious as to why you get only two decimal precision.

Comment: @eroot163pi: the OP is trying to obtain this effect.

Comment: The question is incomplete, because you don't state in which exact range you want these random numbers (and we have to guess that you want them uniform, don't we ?).

Comment: It is a pity that the question was closed as already having answers. Because the rounding strategy is not the correct one, as it introduces a bias, and there is no place to discuss this now.

Comment: @yves i agree with you

Comment: @december try to generate random integers from 0 to 99 using random.randint and divide by 100. This should give you floats upto 2 decimal without bias. I think....also i wish question is reopened to discussion

Comment: @eroot163pi: you can vote for reopening.

Comment: @DecemberB: Should `0.0` be a possible output? What about `1.0`? What distribution of output values do you want: all output values equally likely? Note that the accepted `round(x, 2)` solution does not produce all values with equal likelihood: `0.0` and `1.0` are roughly half as likely to occur as any other value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the format method in python if you want EXACTLY 2 digits after the decimal point (for example if you want 0.90):

```
import random

x = random.random()
print("{:.2f}".format(x))
```

or if you are fine with numbers like 0.9:

```
import random

x = random.random()
print(round(x,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Want this?

```
import random
round(random.random(), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `print(round(random.random(), 2))`